# Spring BeanUtils , copyProperties and apply operation

Tags: java, spring

I am using BeanUtils from Spring to copy properties between two objects of the same class. I am wondering if there is a way to copy the properties from the source to the target after applying an operation to it.
Lets say all the properties are Integers. Is there a way to "configure" BeanUtils so after calling copyProperties the target object would have the source object values  `+ 1` ?

Comment: No. Copy does exactly that copy the values.

Answer (score 1):

No. BeanUtils has three overloaded `copyProperties(...)` methods, but they just copy from the `source` Bean to the `target` Bean.

The first one copies all the properties, which match, from source to target.

```
copyProperties(Object source, Object target);
```

The second one copies only the properties specified at an editable class or interface.

```
copyProperties(Object source, Object target, Class<?> editable)
```

The third one copies all the properties from source to target, except the ones specified.

```
copyProperties(Object source, Object target, String... ignoreProperties)
```

If you want to do something like that, you would have to create your own mapper class, execute the `BeanUtils.copyProperties(...)` method you want and then go through the fields you want to do `+1` and set them again.

Something like

```
public class myMapper {

    public Object map(final Object source) {
        final Object target = new Object();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);
        target.setProperty(target.getProperty() + 1);
        // here modify and set all the properties you want.
        return target;
    }

}
```